# How can I center a div element no matter what the resolution

Tags: css

I have a div element I am centering with percentage margins:

*ie.* `left: 30%;`

The problem is this becomes misaligned and ugly on larger resolutions.

How can I use window calc method with only CSS to maintain my div element be exactly centered at all times during all resolutions?

**Please note: ELEMENT IS POSITIONED FIXED!**

Comment: you dont use `margin: 0 auto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your element always centered wrt any screen resolution.

```css
.centered {
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="centered">center</div>
```

Comment: translateX(-50%, -50%) is an invalid property value but translateX(-50%) works, like @Andy Hoffman mentions below.

Answer (score 1):

This ensures that your element will be horizontally centered, regardless of its parent's dimensions, position or width:

```css
.el {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="el">Always horizontally centered</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using viewport width and height help?

example on left 30% of your window width:

```
left:30vw;
```

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since your element is `position:fixed`, then bring it back to *true* center with a horizontal transform.

Using an X transform, you can bring it back to center regardless of the width. This is advantageous because without the transform, you would have to explicitly claim the width of the element, then give it a negative margin of half its width.

Way too much work, if you ask me. Plus, fixed-widths can get you into trouble.

This 2D transform method is supported across all major browsers **[except for Opera Mini and IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)**.

```
<div>Element</div>
```

---

```
div {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27b94jh3/7/

Answer (score 0):

For new browsers, flexbox is always an option:

```css
.container {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.spacer {
  height:2000px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Always Centered
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

I added a `div` for spacing, to demo the scroll.